# docker network with only one available address

Tags: docker, networking

Is there a way to create a Docker network with just only two (mask 31) available IP address?

I tried this:

```
docker network create uas --subnet=255.255.255.254/31
```

but ends with error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to allocate gateway (): No available addresses on this pool
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do the same thing right now.

From what I can see, this was raised as an issue in the official GitHub repository [moby/moby#32444](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32444), but the fix [42626](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/42626) was only merged recently on Jun 8, 2022, and not yet released.

So in short, it is a known issue and we could probably expect it to be fixed in the upcoming release.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I could not imagine your scenario to such a requirement. Maybe you could do some make-up for for question.
But, I should point out that the error message you got above is already showing what exact the problem is. As a sub-network, it must include a gateway and a broadcast address, which means: there must be more than 2 addresses in this sub-network so we can assign valid IP address for other use.
Hope this could help~

Comment: _it must include a gateway and a broadcast address_ this is not true. See [RFC 3021 "Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3021).

Comment: First of all, no, this is not correct at all. A subnet does not need a broadcast domain. Hence RFC3021. Also, why is a `/31` so far fetched with a docker container? Perfect example is if you are trying to connect to a router directly to your container. No need for broadcast domain. This is done a lot when configuring BGP between the transit subnet of two interfaces.